# SpecFlow steps failing with Extent Report

Tags: c#, specflow, extentreports

I am trying to integrate Extent Reports to my Selenium and SpecFlow project but I am getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at the the *[AfterStep]* (highlighted below) after the test launches successfully, and then go to the URL and then fail at the first step of execution.

Error occurs here:

```
if (stepType == "Given") // <-- Error occurs here
{
    _feature = _scenario.CreateNode<Given>(stepType + " " + ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
}
else if (stepType == "When")
    _scenario.CreateNode<When>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
else if (stepType == "And")
    _scenario.CreateNode<And>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
else if (stepType == "Then")
    _scenario.CreateNode<Then>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
```

This is the whole hook/base file:

```
private static ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
private static FeatureContext _featureContext;
private static ExtentReports _extentReports;
private static ExtentHtmlReporter _extentHtmlReporter;
private static ExtentTest _feature;
private static ExtentTest _scenario;


[BeforeTestRun]
public static void BeforeTestRun()
{
    _extentHtmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"...\AutoTestFramework\TestResult.html");
    _extentReports = new ExtentReports();
    _extentReports.AttachReporter(_extentHtmlReporter);
}

[BeforeFeature]
public static void BeforeFeatureStart(FeatureContext featureContext)
{
    if(null != featureContext)
    {
        _feature = _extentReports.CreateTest<Feature>(featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title,
            featureContext.FeatureInfo.Description);
    }
}


[BeforeScenario]
public void BeforeScenario(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
{
    ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
    option.AddArguments("start-maximized");
    //option.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
    //option.AddArguments("--headless");

    new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
    Driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
    Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    //_objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(Driver);

    if(null != scenarioContext)
    {
        _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        _feature.CreateNode<Feature>(scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title,
            scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Description);
    }
}

[AfterStep]
public void AfterEachStep()
{
    var stepType = ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType.ToString();

    if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError == null)
    {
        if (stepType == "Given") // <-- Error occurs here
        {
            _feature = _scenario.CreateNode<Given>(stepType + " " + ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
        }
        else if (stepType == "When")
            _scenario.CreateNode<When>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
        else if (stepType == "And")
            _scenario.CreateNode<And>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
        else if (stepType == "Then")
            _scenario.CreateNode<Then>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
    }
    else if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError != null)
    {
        if (stepType == "Given")
            _scenario.CreateNode<Given>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message);
        else if (stepType == "When")
            _scenario.CreateNode<When>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message);
        else if (stepType == "And")
            _scenario.CreateNode<And>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message);
        else if (stepType == "Then")
            _scenario.CreateNode<Then>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message);
    }
}

[AfterTestRun]
public static void AfterTestRun()
{
    _extentReports.Flush();
}

[AfterScenario]
public void AfterScenario()
{
    Driver.Quit();
}
```

Error message and stack trace:

```
 The "Fer" button is displayed and takes the user to the self-Fration page in Login
   Source: Login.feature line 36

Test has multiple result outcomes
   3 Failed

Results

    1)  The "Fer" button is displayed and takes the user to the self-Fration page
      Duration: 11.5 sec

      Message: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

      Stack Trace: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Base.AfterEachStep() line 77
TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType) line 404
TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent) line 365
RunnerTestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
TestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd() line 345
RunnerTestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd()
TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) line 572
TestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg) line 686
RunnerTestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg)
TestRunner.Given(String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg, String keyword) line 80
LoginFeature.TheFerButtonIsDisplayedAndTakesTheUserToTheSelf_FrationPage() line 37
StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
TestNodeTask.Execute()

      Standard Output: 

-> -> Loading plugin ...\repos\AutoTestFramework\AutoTestFramework\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\AutoTestFramework.dll
-> -> Loading plugin ...\repos\AutoTestFramework\AutoTestFramework\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\LivingDoc.SpecFlowPlugin.dll
-> -> Loading plugin ...\repos\AutoTestFramework\AutoTestFramework\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecRun.Runtime.SpecFlowPlugin.dll
-> -> Using default config

Given I go to the Fry Portal login page
-> done: Constants.GivenIGoToTheFryPortalLoginPage() (7.7s)


      Standard Error: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AutoTestFramework.Base.Base.AfterEachStep() in ...\repos\AutoTestFramework\AutoTestFramework\Base.cs:line 77
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 404
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 365
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Runtime.RunnerTestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd() in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 345
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Runtime.RunnerTestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 572
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 686
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Runtime.RunnerTestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.Given(String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg, String keyword) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\TestRunner.cs:line 80
   at AutoTestFramework.Features.LoginFeature.TheFerButtonIsDisplayedAndTakesTheUserToTheSelf_FrationPage() in ...\repos\AutoTestFramework\AutoTestFramework\Features\Login.feature:line 37
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestNodeTask.Execute()

    2)  The "Fer" button is displayed and takes the user to the self-Fration page retry #1
      Duration: 2.9 sec

      Message: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

      Stack Trace: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Base.AfterEachStep() line 77
TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType) line 404
TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent) line 365
RunnerTestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
TestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd() line 345
RunnerTestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd()
TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) line 572
TestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg) line 686
RunnerTestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg)
TestRunner.Given(String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg, String keyword) line 80
LoginFeature.TheFerButtonIsDisplayedAndTakesTheUserToTheSelf_FrationPage() line 37
StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
TestNodeTask.Execute()

      Standard Output: 
Given I go to the Fry Portal login page
-> done: Constants.GivenIGoToTheFryPortalLoginPage() (0.9s)


      Standard Error: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AutoTestFramework.Base.Base.AfterEachStep() in ...\repos\AutoTestFramework\AutoTestFramework\Base.cs:line 77
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 404
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 365
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Runtime.RunnerTestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd() in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 345
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Runtime.RunnerTestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 572
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 686
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Runtime.RunnerTestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.Given(String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg, String keyword) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\TestRunner.cs:line 80
   at AutoTestFramework.Features.LoginFeature.TheFerButtonIsDisplayedAndTakesTheUserToTheSelf_FrationPage() in ...\repos\AutoTestFramework\AutoTestFramework\Features\Login.feature:line 37
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestNodeTask.Execute()

    3)  The "Fer" button is displayed and takes the user to the self-Fration page retry #2
      Duration: 2.9 sec

      Message: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

      Stack Trace: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Base.AfterEachStep() line 77
TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType) line 404
TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent) line 365
RunnerTestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
TestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd() line 345
RunnerTestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd()
TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) line 572
TestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg) line 686
RunnerTestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg)
TestRunner.Given(String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg, String keyword) line 80
LoginFeature.TheFerButtonIsDisplayedAndTakesTheUserToTheSelf_FrationPage() line 37
StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
TestNodeTask.Execute()

      Standard Output: 
Given I go to the Fry Portal login page
-> done: Constants.GivenIGoToTheFryPortalLoginPage() (0.9s)


      Standard Error: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AutoTestFramework.Base.Base.AfterEachStep() in ...\repos\AutoTestFramework\AutoTestFramework\Base.cs:line 77
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 404
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 365
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Runtime.RunnerTestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd() in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 345
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Runtime.RunnerTestExecutionEngine.OnStepEnd()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 572
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 686
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Runtime.RunnerTestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.Given(String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg, String keyword) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\TestRunner.cs:line 80
   at AutoTestFramework.Features.LoginFeature.TheFerButtonIsDisplayedAndTakesTheUserToTheSelf_FrationPage() in ...\repos\AutoTestFramework\AutoTestFramework\Features\Login.feature:line 37
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestNodeTask.Execute()
```

Comment: It is unclear which line of code is throwing a NullReferenceException. Can you please [edit] your question and place a comment above the line that throws the exception? Ideally it would be nice to see the stack trace of that exception as well.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Thank you, I have updated my original post to make it clear where I am getting the exception. I also added the stack trace in the original post. Thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately the line of code you are highlighting will never throw a NullReferenceException. I also do not see an error message or stacktrace in the question. Typically a NullReferenceException gets thrown for code like `foo.Bar` where `foo` is null.

Comment: I see the error message and stacktrace now. It got included in the C# code. Please put errors and stack traces in their own code block or in their own block quote. Putting too much in a code block causes some of the contents to be hidden until you scroll down, which is why I didn't see the error information at first. I edited your question to clarify it.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have updated it now to include the error message and stack traces. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Are you running tests in parallel?

Comment: @GregBurghardt No. Just individual test

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the error isn't occurring at `var stepType = ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType.ToString();` - that is the only line that has the `foo.Bar` syntax typically associated with null exceptions.